# My layout looks different form emulator to emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

$avtivity main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/p"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.nanda.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/tblack"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/MyButton1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"


                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/mo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:text="@string/button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MyButton1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="@string/moddle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"




                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/tblack"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:cropToPadding="false" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/MyButton2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"


                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/mo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button"
                android:text="@string/button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MyButton2"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="@string/moddle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/tblack"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/MyButton3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"


                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/mo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button"
                android:text="@string/button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MyButton3"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="@string/moddle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                android:background="@drawable/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/tblack"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/MyButton4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"


                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/mo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button"
                android:text="@string/button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MyButton4"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="@string/moddle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/tblack"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/MyButton5"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"


                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/mo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button"
                android:text="@string/button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MyButton5"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="@string/moddle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/tblack"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_below=""/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/MyButton6"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"


                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/mo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/button"
                android:text="@string/button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MyButton6"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="@string/moddle"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

when I run this app

its different from one emulator to other,
in small size screen my layout is fitting it, but when I run it on the big screen, emulator the layout is moving to the top,
I want my app to look same on both big screen and small screen
please, anyone, help me 
advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you already try this:
[SDP - a scalable size unit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

it will make same view regardless of resolution of device

Comment: I don't know what is sdp

Comment: There are some example in that link